# Invalid option '9.0' for /langversion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm receiving the following when I attempt to build my Unity project.

It builds in Unity without complaint, but fails in Rider when I attempt to rebuild solution (previously it didn't).

Versions
Unity:2021.2.8f1
Odin:3.0.12
JB Rider: 2021.3.3

```
Sirenix.OdinInspector.CompatibilityLayer
  Invalid option '9.0' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default

Sirenix.OdinInspector.UnityMathematics
  Invalid option '9.0' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default
```

Comment: What exactly do you rebuild the solution in Rider for?

Comment: Good question. When adding a new script in Unity, Rider fails to detect it properly (context help, etc. doesn't work) initially. I need to open Odin and choose Generate DLL to get it to work again.

The only possible source of this I could find so far was this Odin error when I rebuild. So mainly a stab in the dark at solving another issue.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? I am facing the same issue with Rider 2022.1.2 and Unity 2021.3.4f1.

Comment: @scho I've updated my question with the solution to my problem. If Odin isn't involved in yours, then it's likely not going to assist you, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a library which Odin was picking up called "ListStack" when it was rebuilding it's DLL.

I had to go into Odin's supported types and deselect it. I couldn't find the actual reference in my code.

It was also preventing the WebGL build, but played fine in the Unity editor.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who winds up here in the future, this was the solution that worked for me for the invalid /langversion issue:

Despite the error message claiming that it is related to the /langversion, and csproj files, the actual solution was to change the MSBuild version from Auto detected (4.0) to 16.0 (I used the embedded JetBrains path).

https://forum.unity.com/threads/issues-with-running-code-in-rider-and-long-enter-play-mode-times.1114033/